# Python re sub - extract data between data that varies

Tags: python, regex

If I have this data

```
NIST SP 800-53 :: CM-7
NIST SP 800-53A :: CM-7.1 (iii)
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: CM-7 b
NIST SP 800-53 :: IA-5 (1) (c)
NIST SP 800-53A :: IA-5 (1).1 (v)
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: IA-5 (1) (c)
NIST SP 800-53 :: IA-7
NIST SP 800-53A :: IA-7.1
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: IA-7
NIST SP 800-53 :: IA-7
NIST SP 800-53A :: IA-7.1
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: IA-7
NIST SP 800-53 :: SC-28
NIST SP 800-53A :: SC-28.1
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: SC-28
NIST SP 800-53 :: SC-23 (3)
NIST SP 800-53A :: SC-23 (3).1 (ii)
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: SC-23 (3)
NIST SP 800-53 :: SC-3
NIST SP 800-53A :: SC-3.1 (ii)
```

And I only want to retrieve the value after the ":: " and nothing else, using strip to remove white spaces, how to I use re.sub to get this into variable in which I can print.

For a line such as

```
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: IA-5 (1) (c)
```

All I am after is the string "IA-5" --- cutting the first part of the string off and anything after starting at the first open parentheses or space? I must account for lines that don't have a parentheses like like this line:

```
NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4 :: CM-7 b
```

I want the substring "CM-7" nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>You don't require regex. Don't follw [xkcd 208](https://www.xkcd.com/208/)</sub>

Assuming those parts won't contain spaces or `::` themselves, just split on `::` and then on spaces

```
for line in open("data.txt"):
  parts = line.split("::")
  parts = list(map(str.strip, parts))
  print(parts[1].split()[0].strip())
```

Output

```
CM-7
CM-7.1
CM-7
IA-5
IA-5
IA-5
IA-7
IA-7.1
IA-7
IA-7
IA-7.1
IA-7
SC-28
SC-28.1
SC-28
SC-23
SC-23
SC-23
SC-3
SC-3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `re.sub`, use `re.findall`:

```
import re
data = list(filter(None, input.split('\n')))
last_data = [re.findall('(?<=::\s)[a-zA-Z]+\-[\d\.]+', i)[0] for i in data]
```

Output:

```
['CM-7', 'CM-7.1', 'CM-7', 'IA-5', 'IA-5', 'IA-5', 'IA-7', 'IA-7.1', 'IA-7', 'IA-7', 'IA-7.1', 'IA-7', 'SC-28', 'SC-28.1', 'SC-28', 'SC-23', 'SC-23', 'SC-23', 'SC-3', 'SC-3.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

`[re.sub('.*?::\s*(\S*)\s.*', '\g<1>', line, flags=re.DOTALL) for line in data]` will work just fine :)

I'm a big fan of the capture group subbing.

(the `re.DOTALL` is to handle pesky whitespace at the end of line)